# How can i install python 2.7.3 on ubuntu using ansible

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, ansible

I am trying to install`python 2.7.3` from `ansible` on `ubuntu 12`

```
- name: Add snake repository
  apt_repository: repo='ppa:fkrull/deadsnakes' state=present
- name: Install postgresql
  apt: pkg=python2.7 state=present 
  sudo: true
  remote_user: vagrant
```

I get this error

```
TASK: [Add snake repository] **************************************************
failed: [192.168.0.28] => {"cmd": ["apt-key", "adv", "--recv-keys", "--keyserver", "hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80", "FF3997E83CD969B409FB24BC5BB92C09DB82666C"], "failed": true, "rc": 2}
stderr: gpg: requesting key DB82666C from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: no writable keyring found: eof
gpg: error reading `[stream]': general error
gpg: Total number processed: 0

stdout: Executing: gpg --ignore-time-conflict --no-options --no-default-keyring --secret-keyring /etc/apt/secring.gpg --trustdb-name /etc/apt/trustdb.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --primary-keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --recv-keys --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 FF3997E83CD969B409FB24BC5BB92C09DB82666C

msg: gpg: requesting key DB82666C from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: no writable keyring found: eof
gpg: error reading `[stream]': general error
gpg: Total number processed: 0

FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting
```

what is apt_key , how to get it

Answer (score 2):

PPA that you are trying to use does NOT have Python 2.7.3. At the time of this writing it only has 2.7.2 and 2.7.6
If you want Python 2.7.3, it comes in standard `precise-updates` repo http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise-updates/python-all

If you still want to use that PPA, before you can use `apt_repository` you should use [`apt_key`](http://docs.ansible.com/apt_key_module.html) module to add that PPA's signing key.
Update your playbook to have this before your apt_repo block:

```
- name: Add snake repo signing key
  apt_key: id=DB82666C
           url=http://keyserver.ubuntu.com:11371/pks/lookup?op=get&search=0x5BB92C09DB82666C
           state=present
```

Also name if your package install block is "Postgresql"..You probably want to fix that.